# Correct way of adding EmbedBlock into StreamField via code?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a Page model with a StreamField:

```
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.embeds.blocks import EmbedBlock

class SomeModel(Page):
    stream_field = StreamField(
        [
            ("embed", EmbedBlock()),
        ]
    )
```

I would like to create a new `SomeModel` instance via code and populate the `stream_field` with an embed value. E.g.

```
from wagtail.embeds.blocks import EmbedValue

some_model_instance = SomeModel()

embed_url = "https://youtube.com/something"

embed_value = EmbedValue(embed_url)

embed_block = ("embed", embed_value)

some_model_instance.stream_field.append(embed_block)

some_model_instance.save()
```

The above code pattern works without error, but when I view the content in the Wagtail Admin UI the field is empty (as if nothing was provided).

How can I add content to a Wagtail StreamField EmbedBlock via code?

Comment: I have tried wrapping the `embed_value` in an `EmbedBlock`, but get the error: AttributeError: 'EmbedBlock' object has no attribute 'url'

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to add an Embed to a StreamField is as follows:

```
from wagtail.embeds.embeds import get_embed

some_model_instance = SomeModel()

embed_url = "https://youtube.com/something"

embed = get_embed(embed_url)

embed_block = ("embed", embed)

some_model_instance.stream_field.append(embed_block)

some_model_instance.save()
```